# getElementsByTagName in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the syntax of pure JavaScript; Do you know why "getElementsByTagName" is not working in my simple test:

```
 var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(btn);


btn.onclick=function(){
    alert('entered');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="test";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/ZH8XA/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
```

instead of

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns array of matched elements. So use `0` index to access the button.

More about [**getElementsByTagName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)

**OR**

You can provide the specific id on button and can use `getElementById()`

**JS**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
```

**HTML**

```
   <button id="myButton">....</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName returns an array, not a single element.  You need to loop through your results and attach a function to each one individually, something like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for( var x=0; x < buttons.length; x++ ) {

   buttons[x].onclick = function(){

       alert('entered');
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="test";
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getElementsByTagName()
```

returns an array, which you have to access by their index.

For selecting a single element, use `getElementById('id here');`

The method itself says get **Elements**.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace btn by btn[0] like this-

```
   btn[0].onclick=function(){
     alert('entered');
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="test"; 
   }
```