# JavaScript: getElementsByTagName()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Can i add an animation to all the links in the page?

Here the code

```
  var words = document.links;

  words.onmouseover = function() {
    words.classList.toggle("tada");
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code should work. It should only touch the first anchor in the page, but its using querySelector instead of querySelectorAll or getElementsByTagName.

Comment: I don't see you using `getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelectorAll` anywhere!

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6967297/218196 and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22727403/218196

Comment: ok sorry i'll delete, i've searched but i did find. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, if you only want `<a>` elements that have a `href` attribute, you can just use the `document.links` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getElementsByTagName('a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [`querySelectorAll('a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) functions should work as expected returning either an `HTMLCollection` or a `NodeList` respectively, both of which will require you to iterate through to actually set up your event handler :

```
// Get your links
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
// Iterate through them and set up your event handlers
for(var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){
      links[l].onmouseover = function () {
         this.classList.toggle("tadan");
      };
}
```

It's also important to note that `getElementsByTagName()` will return a "live" `HTMLCollection` of elements, whereas `querySelectorAll()` will return a "non-live" `NodeList`, which can affect how the elements in these are used.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName seems to indicate that getElementsByTagName returns an HTMLCollection.  Is the only difference between an HTMLCollection and a NodeList that the HTMLCollection is always live?

Comment: You are correct. For some reason I suppose I was referencing the wrong function initially. But yes, the `HTMLCollection` is live and the `NodeList` is not.

Answer (score 0):

gotta loooopp

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for(var i=link.length; i--;)
    link[i].onmouseover = function () {
          this.classList.toggle("tadan");
    };
```

**OR** you do have jQuery tagged so you could just

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('tadan');
});
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, might as well do it all the jQuery way: `$(this).toggleClass('tadan');`

Comment: You can simplify the code if you use `this` instead of `z` inside the event handler. Then you can omit the IIFE.

Comment: good points, thank you.