# i want to change color of elements within <code> tag not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the color of elements that are only within the `<code>` tag but does not work.

I dont want to use document.GetElementByID as per the answers here [getElementsByTagName in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727403/getelementsbytagname-in-javascript)

Below is my original code.

```html
<div id="wmd-post">
<code>
<p>&lt;/span&gt;</p> <!-- i would want only this to change color -->
</code>
 
<p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>  <!-- i would NOT want this to change color -->

</div>


<script>
 
var text = document.getElementById("wmd-post"); 
var str = text.innerHTML;
str = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>'); 
document.getElementById("wmd-post").innerHTML = str;

</script>
```

---

What i have tried is

```html
<div id="wmd-post">
<code>
  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
</code>
 
<p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>  

</div>


<script>
 
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('code');
var str = text.innerHTML;
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
        str[i] = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>');
        document.getElementsByTagName("code").innerHTML = str[i];
}

</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` with multiple elements in it. You have to index it to operate on specific elements.

Comment: how come you don't want to use css?

Comment: @Barmar even if i try that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727403/getelementsbytagname-in-javascript . I still cant be able to make the code change color. please

Comment: @krushiovida You can't assign to `str[i]`. `str` is a string, not an array.

Comment: @Barmar i have tried to edit my question so as it does not look like a duplicate please allow me to get some answers

Comment: @krushiovida , try my solution

Comment: @ant I dont want to use css

Comment: @chiragpatel thanks great soln

Comment: *I dont want to use css* That's what CSS is for. This is roughly equivalent to saying, I want to pound in a nail, but don't want to use a hammer. Then fine, use your shoe instead.

Comment: I've reopened the question and posted an answer. But it's basically saying the same thing as in the duplicate I linked to earlier. I'm not sure why you couldn't get it from that. If you can't generalize a pattern like this, you're not going to go far as a programmer.

Comment: I wrote an answer for you, but yeah, essentially what @torazaburo said.  Future maintenance is going to be a nightmare if you manipulate the dom and set styles in your javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/da7evneb)

You just have to change a Script of your code , Here is the script.

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('code');
var str = text[0].innerHTML;

            
str = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>');
document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: This ignores the wmd-post id.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know why you're not using css, but here goes:

html:

```
<div id="wmd-post">
<code>
  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
</code>

<p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>  

</div>
```

JS:

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];
var str = text.innerHTML;

str = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>');

document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].innerHTML = str;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u8ystwyg/1/

A css only solution:

```
<style>
  code { color: red; }
</style>

<div id="wmd-post">
<code>
  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
</code>

<p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a better css soln? I have searched entire day but its like impossible

Comment: This ignores the wmd-post id.

Comment: dont you think that the css will change color off everything not specific elements.

Comment: you mentioned in your original post that you only wanted to change the color of text inside 'code' elements.  that little bit of css will do that.  if there is a specific hierarchy you want to target, then yes, the css will change a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your question had the jQuery tag before it was edited away by another user. In case you want to use jQuery, here is one solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wmd-post > code").css("color", "red");
});
```

Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r28swva/2/)

Comment: That was a simple soln but the problem is it will change all the elements yet i only want to change color of a specific element

Comment: It changes the color of the code element only. Check out the link

Comment: I mean, within the tag `<code>` , i would only need to change colors of specific elements not all. Your solution will change color of everything withing the `<code>` element

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. You need to loop over the list.

```js
var codes = document.getElementsByTagName('code');
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
  var str = codes[i].innerHTML;
  str = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>');
  codes[i].innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<div id="wmd-post">
  <code>
  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
</code>

  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example using [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) which basically gets all elements in the document with the specified tag (in your case `code` tag). You can replace the "target" string using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) .

```js
(function(){
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('code'),
str = text[0].innerHTML;
str = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span class="red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>');
text[0].innerHTML = str;
})();
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wmd-post">
<code>
  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
</code>
 <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're calling `getElementsByTagName` twice?